# Zeus not reloading code changes in model files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zeus

I've recently discovered Zeus and it's fantastic really speeds up my feedback loop when developing it's just that when I'm making changes to my model like adding a new method Zeus doesn't restart and the new method isn't loaded.

I'm not sure where to start debugging but I'm using Rails 4.0.2, ruby 2.0.0p353 and Rspec + Capybara for testing.

Anyone have any ideas or help that would be fantastic.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: @KieranAndrews I'm using foreman as my server

Comment: Check this link for more information on zeus with foreman: https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/92 - You may need to reconfigure foreman.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `unicorn` this could be your problem. Try using `thin` instead

> **Zeus:**
>   Reloads models correctly when modifying callbacks and scopes, which
>   is not always the case for servers with hot-reload, such as Unicorn.
>   It also reloads views when writing integration specs.([source](http://bitzesty.com/blog/2013/05/enable-tdd-with-faster-ruby-on-rails-stack-reloading/))

You may also need to reconfigure foreman. Check this thread for information on foreman support with Zeus: https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/92